# Invalid left-hand side in assignment while concatenating

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table, concatenation

```js
function nowakolumna(){
    document.getElementById("listacen") += '<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>';
}
```

i have this code for adding new column in table but when i try to execute it via button with onclick listener i get this error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. Anyone help.

Comment: The `.getElementById()` function returns an object reference, and so `+=` does not make sense. You probably want `.innerHTML += ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Operator `+=` on a document element object is not defined. You have to do this:

```js
function nowakolumna() {
    document.getElementById("listacen").innerHTML += '<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: it is 12 a.m. and i'm the dumbest person rn. thanks man im closing.